# Regional sites/subsites on Area 51

Tags: feature-request, area-51, site-proposal

I am thinking about a site proposal for area 51, but it would be nice to have a different sections for country-specific questions (I'm Italian), maybe in other languages. I think that creating two different sites would be silly (people from the region specific site could and should benefit from the information on the general one), but I also feel that having just one site and using tags to filter questions wouldn't be right either: having questions in different languages on the home page would be too chaotic... Do you think there is a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there are 3 categories of region- and language-based proposals.

In the first category there are non-English topic-centered proposals.

- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2912/persian-information-technology-and-computer
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10120/software-testing-in-portuguese

I see no problem with this type of proposals. If there is enough X-speaking Y-experts, then a site for them is viable and should be created, even for X != English. Fair enough, not everyone speaks English. There are some problems with attracting enough initial commitment, but that's just a technicality.

In the second category there are area-based proposals.

- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8157/maine
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10259/iceland

Proposals in this category are rather poorly defined and target two separate groups at the same time: locals and tourists. With some luck such sites might evolve into valuable resources for tourists, but degenerating into local gossip site is also a likely scenario.

Then, there's the third category: proposals for anyone to talk in any language about anything that happens anywhere.

- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7839/geographic-specific-information
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3253/programming-q-a-site-non-english

In my opinion that's deep in the Yahoo-Answers-land of chaos.

Comment: The problem is: the topic I am thinking about is broad enough to deserve an international site, but it would be extremely useful as a regional site, too, as there are many problems specific to the Italian situation. Say, for example, that you want to make your own startup: there is plenty of useful information on the Internet, but most of it is US centric and not applicable to the Italian situation. What I think would fit best is a general site (say Startups and new enterprises) with a subsection for region-specific topics...

Comment: @Miko: How about tags such as [italy], [italian-job-market] and [italian-tax-law] within a major global site? Wouldn't that enough (apart from language issues)?

Comment: Probably, though I feel that a specific site would get more people participating...